# How do I hide the load more button for this jquery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am trying to make a website but I am very new to the jquery stuff and I added jquery load more comment into my website

**My question is, I have a load more button that works the way I intended it to work however when all the data are loaded or when there is no comment I can't seem to get the load button to turn hidden**

//jquery script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var commentCount = 20;
  var qidNow = "<?php echo $qid; ?>";
  $("button").click(function() {
    commentCount = commentCount + 20;
    $("#comments").load("includes/load-comments.inc.php", {
      commentNewCount: commentCount,
      qid: qidNow
    });
  });
});
```

//load-comments page

```
<?PHP
require 'dbh.inc.php';
include 'function.inc.php';

$commentNewCount = $_POST["commentNewCount"];
$qid = $_POST["qid"];
$count = 0;



  $sqlComment = "SELECT comment, commentTime, commenterId FROM comments WHERE commentOn = ?
   LIMIT ?";

  $stmtComment = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtComment, $sqlComment)) {
    header("Location: ../viewtopic.php?error=sqlerror4");
    exit();
  } else {
    //bind parameter to the placeholder
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtComment, "ii", $qid, $commentNewCount);
    //run parameter inside database
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtComment);
    $commentData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtComment);
  }

  if (mysqli_num_rows($commentData) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentData)) {
      $count++;
      echo "<div class='individualComment'>";
      echo "<div class='commentCount'> คอมเม้นที่" . $count . "</div>";
      echo "<div class='actualComment'>" . $row['comment'] . "</div>";
      echo "<div class='commentDateBx'>" . dateReformat($row['commentTime']) . "</div>";
      echo "<div class='commenterIdBx'>ID :" . $row['commenterId'] . "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
 }else {
    echo "There is no comment yet";
  }
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to hide the button?

Comment: My initial thought would be to check the length of comments, and if the number of comments in the incrementor would be *greater* than the total comments, then to either not render or apply a class with display: none on the button element.

Comment: There are issues with your PHP logic. One is that if you try to load more comments but you have reached the end of the comments, you program is going to say there is no comment yet. There should be a separate logic that checks if there is any comment. At any point a comment, if deletable, may be deleted. Two, your count does not really work because it starts from 0 each time you start the script. If you use a session variable you can keep track. I don't see the need to show the comment count number per comment.  Use .complete to check the data for a value says no more records.